# Cannot install Oracle Grid on Oracle Linux 6.4

Tags: installation, oracle-asm, oracle-grid-control

I have an Oracle database 11gr2 and I want to install Oracle Grid on Oracle Linux 6.4.
At first, I have installed Oracle Grid with the tutorial on this website:

https://eudba.wordpress.com/2012/08/10/installing-oracle-11g-on-oracle-linux-6-with-asm-eng/

When the grid installation is finished, I have an error that says: "the Oracle grid service can not start".

When I want to install the database with `oracle` user and with ASM, I have an error that I attached it to this question.

Can any one help me?

[image]

Comment: You need to determine why the grid services don't start. Look at the log files, etc.

Comment: What version? You need 11.2.0.3 to install on 6.4

Comment: i want to install 11.2.0.1 on oracle linux 6 , can I ?

Answer (score 0):

The "inappropriate ioctl for device" error probably means it doesn't like either the filesystem or the options with which is mounted. Check your ASM setup and that it actually is using ASM.